# Angular 5 - End to End testing with ngModel

Tags: angular, protractor, angular5, e2e-testing, angular2-ngmodel

in last week we are trying to add e2e testing to our project, but it seems (after a big research in the web) there is no library that can work with Angular ngModel (version 2+).

what can we do ? is there anything except from protractor, which is not support Angular 2 ngModel and binding ?

html example:

I need to look for the following model "data.user.name".

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using proactor for ngModel.
Please consider looking in this [repository](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example)

I already use it. You only need to take the `e2e` directory and looking in the `package.json` what are the dev dependency.

---

Edit for your edit: Accessing internal modal "data.user.name"

You should not use `e2e` tests for that, that is a non sense. You need regular **unit testing** for each of your component. Please consider reproducing what there is in the `*.spec.ts` in the `src` directory. See also the `test-config` in the above mentionned repository.

The official doc for unit testing is [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

**To conclude**:

- Accessing the component and its values, like `data.user.name` is on test-unit side, Angular provide a *heavy* doc (but well made) for that.
- Accessing the DOM is on the e2e side, with regular javascript API, like these:
  `expect(userNameField.getAttribute('value')).toContain('myusername');`

Comment: can you please tell me what is the syntax for this ? i edited the question and added html example to look for

Comment: it looks like nothing changed in your response

Comment: so, you say that we cannot use e2e testing with "ngModel", because it is Angular and have nothing to do with the DOM ?

Comment: End-to-end testing means exactly that, it doesn't mean just DOM state testing. There are perfectly valid test-cases where you would want to test the content/state of a field identified by Angular model or -binding. 

We also have tested this and found it lacking. Protractor seems to be able to help us with an important issue: timing.
But the combination of Angular 4 and Protractor fails when you try to find a field using Angular specific field identifiers.
I believe this is also true for Angular 5, but I haven't tested it first hand.

Please prove me wrong. :-)

Comment: Can't prove, but to help me understand, why do you want to test the ngModel and not just the "value" attribute of your input?